# Invalid path by getpath Function

Tags: java, class, getresource

In java i have to get the exact location of a image which is in a folder(Emoticon) under source directory inside a package but whenever i call

```
String s= (Main.class.getResource("Emoticons\\happy.PNG")).getPath();
System.out.println(s);
emotable.put(emo[0], s);
```

it gives me a invalid path like this

```
/E:/oop/java/emoti/out/production/emoti/sample/Emoticons%5chappy.PNG
```

There is nothing called %5c in the path.Can you tell me why it is coming or how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getResource you need to use not a back-slash but a usual slash:

```
getResource("Emoticons/happy.PNG")
```

Comment: But now after jar conversion the image disappears.

Comment: @Shuvo Because an entry in a jar file is not a file on the file system, which is what `Path` is used for. That's why `getResource()` returns a `URL`, not a `File` or `Path`, because it may not be one of those. To read content, use `getResourceAsStream()`, instead of *assuming* the resource is a file.